# Appending a string from a text field to a filename

Tags: objective-c, string, append, textfield

I'm trying to append a string input from the user to a filename.

```
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data;   name=\"userfile\"; filename= \".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I have a text field I would like the input from the field to be appended before the .jpg.  I've been playing with the string stuff I can find, but don't know how to put them in up above.

Comment: It's usually pretty helpful for you to tag the programming language(s) and/or platform(s) you're using, FYI.

Comment: Assuming you are using objective-c, I don't see what body has to do with a filename? What is body? Where is the filename saved?

Comment: Can you append the user input to the string above, excluding the .jpg? Then, it's easy to append .jpg to the resulting string.

Comment: Sorry... yes I'm using objective C... its a file uploader to a php script to upload an image.   "Can you append the user input to the string above, excluding the .jpg? Then, it's easy to append .jpg to the resulting string. "  Yes this is what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to make some assumptions because your question lacks for clarity, but...

Assuming that body is an `NSMutableData` object.

Assuming that your `UITextField` is named 'textFieldName'.

Assuming, for example, that textFieldName contains the text 'TextInTextField'.

If you are looking to produce a string that reads '`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename= "TextInTextField.jpg"`', then do this:

```
NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename= \"%@.jpg\"\r\n",textFieldName.text];
```

The `stringWithFormat:` & `initWithFormat:` methods of NSString take multiple arguments. The first is a format, or template, that is used by inserting data (from the following arguments), in this case a string, into said format. You indicate where to insert the data with a `%@` or `%i` and so on. In this case you would use `%@` to insert a string.

Of course this can be nested into the original appendData: call like so:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename= \"%@.jpg\"\r\n",textFieldName.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```